# scientific calculator tutorial for iPhone/ipad

Tags: ios

i have been looking for a tutorial for a scientific calculator one the web but i could not find anything. my aim is to learn how to write a calculator app similar to the one in iPhone. does any know of any tutorials that can help me learn how to add scientific functions to a calculator app. keep in mind that i have tried the various versions of the basic calculator and have been through a few of those tutorials and just want to learn and may use the methods to add scientific functions such as rad, sin, cos and some other stuff in the app. i will be great full for any help i can get.

AP

Edit:

since there are no real material on how to build a scientific calculator out there( at least i haven't found anything specific yet) here is the run down of how to build one.

first create a NSObject class to hold your operation methods. ( this is optional, you can set it on top of your getter (.m) file if you like.) call it whatever you want. then declare the following the the header file.

```
{
double operand; 
double savedNumber;
NSString *waitingOperation; 
double waitingOperand;
}

- (void)setOperand:(double)aDouble; 
- (double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation;
- (void)performWaitingOperation;

@end
```

then in the .m file of your NSObject class declare the methods that operates your functions. something like the following:

```
-(void)setOperand:(double)num
{
operand=num;
}
-(double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation
{
if([operation isEqual:@"sqrt"]){
    operand = sqrt(operand);
}else if ([operation isEqual:@"1/x"]){
    if(operand)
        operand = 1 / operand;
}else if ([operation isEqual:@"2/x"]){
    if(operand)
        operand = 2 / operand;
}else if ([operation isEqual:@"3/x"]){
    if(operand)
        operand = 3 / operand;
}else if ([operation isEqual:@"+/-"]){
    if(operand)
        operand = (-1) * operand;
}else if ([operation isEqual:@"sin"]){
    operand = sin(operand);
}else if ([operation isEqual:@"sinh"]){//you can add more scientific functions in the same way to this list.
    operand = sinh(operand);
}else if ([operation isEqual:@"cos"]){
    operand = cos(operand);
}else if ([operation isEqual:@"cosh"]){
    operand = cosh(operand);
}else if ([operation isEqual:@"tan"]){
    operand = tan(operand);
}else if ([operation isEqual:@"tanh"]){
    operand = tanh(operand);
}else if ([operation isEqual:@"M"]){
    savedNumber = operand;
}else if ([operation isEqual:@"M+"] ){
    savedNumber += operand;
}else if ([operation isEqual:@"M-"] ){
    savedNumber -= operand;
}else if ([operation isEqual:@"Recall"]){
    [self setOperand:savedNumber];
}else if ([operation isEqual:@"C"]){
    savedNumber = 0; 
    operand = 0;
    waitingOperand = 0;
    savedNumber= 0; 
}else {
    [self performWaitingOperation];
    waitingOperation = operation;       
    waitingOperand = operand;
}
return operand;
    }
    - (void) performWaitingOperation
    {
if([@"+" isEqual:waitingOperation]){
    operand = waitingOperand + operand ;
} else if([@"-" isEqual:waitingOperation]){
    operand = waitingOperand - operand ;
}else if([@"X" isEqual:waitingOperation]){
    operand = waitingOperand * operand ;
}else if([@"/" isEqual:waitingOperation]){
    if(operand)
        operand = waitingOperand / operand ;
}
    }
```

now in the view controller that you are trying to display the calculator you need to access all of these functions and display them in your outlets, such as buttons and text field and so on. here is the .h file

```
IBOutlet UILabel *display;
SCalcAI *ai;
BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber;
}

- (IBAction) digitPressed: (UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction) operationPressed: (UIButton *) sender;
```

rememebr to import your NSObject class header on top of this file otherwise you get an error. then in the .m file you need to declare these functions.

```
-(NameofyourNSOBjectClass *) ai
{
 if(!ai)
 {
ai = [[SCalcAI alloc]  init];
}
return ai;
    }

    - (IBAction) digitPressed: (UIButton *)sender
    {

 NSString *digit = [[sender titleLabel] text];
    if(userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber){
        [display setText:[[display text] stringByAppendingString:digit]];
    } else{
        [display setText:digit];
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber = YES;
    }

}
- (IBAction) operationPressed: (UIButton *) sender
{
    if(userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber){
        [[self ai] setOperand:[[display text] doubleValue]];
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber = NO;
    }
    NSString *operation = [[sender titleLabel] text];
    double result = [[self ai] performOperation:operation]; 
    [display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result]];
}
```

then hook up all the buttons to the operations they need to be connected in the storyboard or xib. thats that. the above is the skeleton version of the whole thing but I'm sure you can build on that. if you need help send me message.

Comment: This is funky :D I'll have to setup an xCode project to test this out & see how it all comes together. If you did in the meantime have a git repository with a sample app of your workings that would be great. As one of the things that made my code egregiously horrible was the use of trying to create delegate methods for the +9 buttons I had consisting of 10 numbers, basic functions and then tan, sqrt, etc.. There must be a way of combining everything together nicely rather than connecting all by UIButtons to UIActions. alas, your code here will get me started on making the maths code look nice.

Comment: Hey, I have a few questions: 
1) other than keeping the code clean, is there any other reason that you have the `waitingOperation` method separately as opposed to having it in the same method?
2) Also, could you please explain what the `operand`, `savedNumber`, `waitingOperation`, and `waitingOperand` are about?

Comment: @Pavan 1) no real reason, I just like clean and approachable code. Saved number refers to when you want to switch operations such as one function then withought pressing equal immediately create another operation. Waiting operation is working with saved number and completes that and waiting operand is the operation that is waiting to take place so needs to be equal to operand. In addition you have waiting operation. In this method you don't need to declare the main function as constant on top of the getter file, that's why I wrote it that way. I'm sure you can do better than what I did.

Comment: @Pavan, if you need a sample project let me know.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Standford iOS programming class](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) cs193p has an example of building a simple calculator. Might be a good place to start. Great course, great videos. Paul Hagarty is a very good instructor. The scientific functions would not be hard to add once you have the core done.

Two resources:
http://www.tusharsharma.in/project/open-source/mathematical-calculator-iphone4/

http://emplementation.blogspot.com/2010/11/ios-development-tutorials-on-itune-u.html

Comment: I've been through what paul did in his lecture. but i just can't figure out how to add the scientific functions. his lecture stops at creating a simple calculator. i also went through the iOS documentation and found a really nice set of codes but again is just a basic. i was hoping to learn more by finding out how to add the scientific functions. but thanks for the reply.

Comment: see the resources I just added

Comment: Thanks Todd. I'll take a look at these source codes. I think these tuts will guide me to the right direction. I guess I have some homework to do. Thanks again.

Comment: @TOMATO I am aware one cannot expect links to work after a while; is there a way you can point us to some new resources? I simply cannot find any tutorials that go beyond the simple calculator.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey What have you gotten up to? what did you end up doing

Comment: @Pavan, I ended up looking at the code within the link and after a bit of tricking I built that damn thing. It turned out to be pretty cool. But that was quiet awhile ago. It was just for learning purpose.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey hey dude, I'm currently in that same position, its a learning curve for me, especially with the damned fuctions and how to handle all the button processing correctly. Atm ive got a load of if functions and messy delegates! I can create audio visual applications and dash board applications for businesses, but give me the task to create a scientific calculator thing and i get stuck! aha. Anyway you could post your learning code project on github bud?

Comment: @Pavan, sure thing man, I'll post the codes tomorrow since is a bit late here in states and I've got to go to bed. I'll tag you as soon as I post it.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey I appreciate it bro. I do appreciate it. I will catch you tomorrow, i look forward to your git. Cheers and sleep well

Comment: @Pavan, i edited my question with a skeleton version of how to build the calculator. it is seriously simple but it just is not what paul does. i had to change a few thing to clean that up. good luck and let me know if you need any more help.